# UIPopoverController Dismissal

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Is there a method called when `UIPopoverController` is dismissed by a touch anywhere outside the rectangle of `UIPopoverController` itself?

Status:

`firstView` has a `navBar`. Its `UINavBarItem` calls a `UIPopoverController` by touch which sets a few values for `firstView`, so `firstView` has to be updated when `UIPopoverController` is dismissed.

(P.S. `viewDidAppear` does not work!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a delegate to the popover; then you have both `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` and `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 you can dismiss your popover controller on touchesBegan method. this method call when you touch on view.


    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [popover dismiss];
    }


Hopefully help this.
```